# Jquery Mobile popup causing page to scroll to top when multipage layout. (on iPhone)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a multipage layout and if I've navigated to a page (even the first page) and the URL now has #PageNumber in it, any closing of any popup in any manner will cause the page to scroll to the top.

Obviously, this isn't ideal, and I want to know if there's anyway to stop it.